Need help filtering solana transactions from QuickNode streams. Extracting amount of SOL sent and direction of swap
Im currently trying to build a whale transaction monitor. I have a QuickNode stream setup that is feeding me live Solana tx's. It gives me raw payload block data that I have the ability to filter down and only receive transactions that fit my requirements.
Currently, I filtered down transactions that involve the raydium AMM v4 liquidity pool Program ID in the instructions along with the targeted token address I want to track.
I have been having a hard time trying to figure out the amount of SOL being sent for the swap and which direction the swap is occuring.
I essentially want to be able to print out basic info about the trade like it says on SOL  scan. "Wallet1 swapped 100 SOL for 344876 Pnut"
here is the current code for my QuickNode stream filter. Thank you!
function main(stream) {
    try {
        const incomingData = stream.data ? stream.data : stream;
        const blocks = Array.isArray(incomingData) ? incomingData : [incomingData];
        const filteredTransactions = [];

        // Define the mint address you want to track
        const TARGET_MINT = "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump"; // Pnut
        
        // Define Raydium's program ID(s)
        const RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_IDS = [
        "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8" // Raydium AMM v4
        ];

        blocks.forEach(block => {
            if (!block.transactions || !Array.isArray(block.transactions)) {
                return;
            }
            block.transactions.forEach(transaction => {
                // Get pre and post token balances
                const preTokenBalances = transaction.meta.preTokenBalances || [];
                const postTokenBalances = transaction.meta.postTokenBalances || [];

                // Check if transaction involves our target mint
                const involvesMint = [...preTokenBalances, ...postTokenBalances].some(
                    balance => balance.mint === TARGET_MINT
                );

                // Check if transaction was successful
                const isSuccessful = transaction.meta.status?.Ok === null;

                // Check if transaction involves Raydium's program ID
                const involvesRaydium = transaction.transaction.message.instructions.some(
                    instruction => RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_IDS.includes(instruction.programId)
                );

                // Convert all balances from lamports to SOL
                const preBalances = transaction.meta.preBalances.map(balance => balance * 1e-9);
                const postBalances = transaction.meta.postBalances.map(balance => balance * 1e-9);
                // Calculate differences between post and pre balances
                const balanceDifferences = postBalances.map((post, index) => post - preBalances[index]);

                
                // calculates the difference between the pre and post balance
                // const difference = postSolbalance - preSolbalance;

                // filters transactions based on the criteria, account bought more SOL than the threshold
                if (involvesMint && isSuccessful && involvesRaydium) {
                    filteredTransactions.push({
                        preSolbalance: preBalances,
                        postSolbalance: postBalances,
                        balanceDifferences: balanceDifferences,
                        transaction: transaction
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        if (filteredTransactions.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return { transactions: filteredTransactions };
    } catch (error) {
        return { error: error.message };
    }
}

// Utility function to decode Base58-encoded strings into byte arrays
function decodeBase58(encoded) {
    const BASE58_ALPHABET = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
        let carry = BASE58_ALPHABET.indexOf(encoded[i]);
        if (carry < 0) return []; // Invalid character

        for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            carry += result[j] * 58;
            result[j] = carry & 0xff;
            carry >>= 8;
        }

        while (carry > 0) {
            result.push(carry & 0xff);
            carry >>= 8;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length && encoded[i] === "1"; i++) {
        result.push(0);
    }

    return result.reverse();
}

Here is the filtered transaction data that QuickNode returns, you can see the fields I pushed to the return object along with the raw transaction data that I also added to it for you to see and examine.
https://solscan.io/tx/4w7mexGkjC8cjqNiFTTTdMV2jakZZLWyLpxtiTAqoFU2yarkF3uKanoX4vdnaiSo11MudhZ7CZT1oy4mV6Wmnnod
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "balanceDifferences": [
        -0.000018001000000822387,
        -2.24909894499433,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        2.249098944999787,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "postSolbalance": [
        90.821916165,
        39871.811491839006,
        1.8254966400000001,
        0.00203928,
        0.00203928,
        0.017124800000000003,
        0.00203928,
        0.45710496,
        0.02335776,
        13009.467872201001,
        0.00359136,
        0.00203928,
        0.45710496,
        1e-9,
        0.9340876800000001,
        0.00114144,
        13.41120169,
        0.00114144,
        0.00114144,
        0
      ],
      "preSolbalance": [
        90.821934166,
        39874.060590784,
        1.8254966400000001,
        0.00203928,
        0.00203928,
        0.017124800000000003,
        0.00203928,
        0.45710496,
        0.02335776,
        13007.218773256001,
        0.00359136,
        0.00203928,
        0.45710496,
        1e-9,
        0.9340876800000001,
        0.00114144,
        13.41120169,
        0.00114144,
        0.00114144,
        0
      ],
      "transaction": {
        "meta": {
          "computeUnitsConsumed": 32797,
          "err": null,
          "fee": 18001,
          "innerInstructions": [
            {
              "index": 3,
              "instructions": [
                {
                  "parsed": {
                    "info": {
                      "amount": "492995165",
                      "authority": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
                      "destination": "2zxMeSRkYa462Zo7v5K7kFKtvpRC4MpvuC1HwA88sCR3",
                      "source": "5UuBVqFSXCQwUJ1TPM4Bd211x5ckK736rMq6aCWTcWbR"
                    },
                    "type": "transfer"
                  },
                  "program": "spl-token",
                  "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                  "stackHeight": 2
                },
                {
                  "parsed": {
                    "info": {
                      "amount": "2249098945",
                      "authority": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
                      "destination": "CTyFguG69kwYrzk24P3UuBvY1rR5atu9kf2S6XEwAU8X",
                      "source": "AEwsZFbKVzf2MqADSHHhwqyWmTWYzruTG1HkMw8Mjq5"
                    },
                    "type": "transfer"
                  },
                  "program": "spl-token",
                  "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                  "stackHeight": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "logMessages": [
            "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
            "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
            "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
            "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
            "Program DnqJ15nYEdFYr6ywvvVWfYLdUTb1nqecECCSYmyWiJe9 invoke [1]",
            "Program DnqJ15nYEdFYr6ywvvVWfYLdUTb1nqecECCSYmyWiJe9 consumed 345 of 41705 compute units",
            "Program DnqJ15nYEdFYr6ywvvVWfYLdUTb1nqecECCSYmyWiJe9 success",
            "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]",
            "Program log: ray_log: A12CYh0AAAAAZeoMhgAAAAABAAAAAAAAAG/F3keKAAAA0IAY50MkAACQM5vM7QcAAMGGDoYAAAAA",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
            "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 22613 compute units",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
            "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4736 of 14987 compute units",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
            "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 32152 of 41360 compute units",
            "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 success"
          ],
          "postBalances": [
            90821916165,
            39871811491839,
            1825496640,
            2039280,
            2039280,
            17124800,
            2039280,
            457104960,
            23357760,
            13009467872201,
            3591360,
            2039280,
            457104960,
            1,
            934087680,
            1141440,
            13411201690,
            1141440,
            1141440,
            0
          ],
          "postTokenBalances": [
            {
              "accountIndex": 1,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "39871809452559",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": 39871.809452559,
                "uiAmountString": "39871.809452559"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 3,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "8718414362093",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": 8718414.362093,
                "uiAmountString": "8718414.362093"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 4,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "0",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": null,
                "uiAmountString": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 6,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "593418273554",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": 593418.273554,
                "uiAmountString": "593418.273554"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 9,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "13009465832921",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": 13009.465832921,
                "uiAmountString": "13009.465832921"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 11,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "0",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": null,
                "uiAmountString": "0"
              }
            }
          ],
          "preBalances": [
            90821934166,
            39874060590784,
            1825496640,
            2039280,
            2039280,
            17124800,
            2039280,
            457104960,
            23357760,
            13007218773256,
            3591360,
            2039280,
            457104960,
            1,
            934087680,
            1141440,
            13411201690,
            1141440,
            1141440,
            0
          ],
          "preTokenBalances": [
            {
              "accountIndex": 1,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "39874058551504",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": 39874.058551504,
                "uiAmountString": "39874.058551504"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 3,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "8717921366928",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": 8717921.366928,
                "uiAmountString": "8717921.366928"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 4,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "0",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": null,
                "uiAmountString": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 6,
              "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
              "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "593911268719",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": 593911.268719,
                "uiAmountString": "593911.268719"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 9,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "13007216733976",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": 13007.216733976,
                "uiAmountString": "13007.216733976"
              }
            },
            {
              "accountIndex": 11,
              "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "owner": "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "uiTokenAmount": {
                "amount": "0",
                "decimals": 9,
                "uiAmount": null,
                "uiAmountString": "0"
              }
            }
          ],
          "rewards": null,
          "status": {
            "Ok": null
          }
        },
        "transaction": {
          "message": {
            "accountKeys": [
              {
                "pubkey": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
                "signer": true,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "AEwsZFbKVzf2MqADSHHhwqyWmTWYzruTG1HkMw8Mjq5",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "28thGvCrfQg4rhWxvU2UHQCj38HXNcYEXVEJoymovSTh",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "2zxMeSRkYa462Zo7v5K7kFKtvpRC4MpvuC1HwA88sCR3",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "34kTKFZL71t7rbdF38Gu8FeRgAjwv64CArpNgYnm8ANc",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "4AZRPNEfCJ7iw28rJu5aUyeQhYcvdcNm8cswyL51AY9i",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "5UuBVqFSXCQwUJ1TPM4Bd211x5ckK736rMq6aCWTcWbR",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "77ZEpy2G9YCTTVyTxXbzQyk1jwk2xFPcqrUauSZKv4o2",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "8cFUa11PV6iUPWRhbP1Zzz15RDvgmL5aHc1d24dmNKL9",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "CTyFguG69kwYrzk24P3UuBvY1rR5atu9kf2S6XEwAU8X",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "DPAkA5GRPVZMGdw2wFvmSAnm8uAFi3vz9gwyFMUiJ4uB",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "EzfJUovwcdCEP4uqdtXBkEQzovzeBx1C9Ht9j8xcX8o2",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "FTf73pRZv47JY9thrq7joM88kbSbmfxHWFBM6X6UfDVN",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": true
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "DnqJ15nYEdFYr6ywvvVWfYLdUTb1nqecECCSYmyWiJe9",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              },
              {
                "pubkey": "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
                "signer": false,
                "source": "transaction",
                "writable": false
              }
            ],
            "addressTableLookups": [],
            "instructions": [
              {
                "accounts": [],
                "data": "Ee9VBV",
                "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
                "stackHeight": null
              },
              {
                "accounts": [],
                "data": "3EanHfLEv9Zh",
                "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
                "stackHeight": null
              },
              {
                "accounts": [],
                "data": "1iYDEFMRUHsu",
                "programId": "DnqJ15nYEdFYr6ywvvVWfYLdUTb1nqecECCSYmyWiJe9",
                "stackHeight": null
              },
              {
                "accounts": [
                  "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                  "4AZRPNEfCJ7iw28rJu5aUyeQhYcvdcNm8cswyL51AY9i",
                  "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
                  "8cFUa11PV6iUPWRhbP1Zzz15RDvgmL5aHc1d24dmNKL9",
                  "AEwsZFbKVzf2MqADSHHhwqyWmTWYzruTG1HkMw8Mjq5",
                  "2zxMeSRkYa462Zo7v5K7kFKtvpRC4MpvuC1HwA88sCR3",
                  "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
                  "DPAkA5GRPVZMGdw2wFvmSAnm8uAFi3vz9gwyFMUiJ4uB",
                  "77ZEpy2G9YCTTVyTxXbzQyk1jwk2xFPcqrUauSZKv4o2",
                  "FTf73pRZv47JY9thrq7joM88kbSbmfxHWFBM6X6UfDVN",
                  "28thGvCrfQg4rhWxvU2UHQCj38HXNcYEXVEJoymovSTh",
                  "EzfJUovwcdCEP4uqdtXBkEQzovzeBx1C9Ht9j8xcX8o2",
                  "34kTKFZL71t7rbdF38Gu8FeRgAjwv64CArpNgYnm8ANc",
                  "Eub2kMmvBDcrRenEt5VywC9P1KGj1S1MhB4vhj7Gzwfj",
                  "5UuBVqFSXCQwUJ1TPM4Bd211x5ckK736rMq6aCWTcWbR",
                  "CTyFguG69kwYrzk24P3UuBvY1rR5atu9kf2S6XEwAU8X",
                  "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa"
                ],
                "data": "674AuuXAuwGcEg7fKdoXEjR",
                "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
                "stackHeight": null
              }
            ],
            "recentBlockhash": "9ZbYfcjbHeMw3aPGFnHmbwvEDUvHpkH9ARoqHTpuMKVC"
          },
          "signatures": [
            "4w7mexGkjC8cjqNiFTTTdMV2jakZZLWyLpxtiTAqoFU2yarkF3uKanoX4vdnaiSo11MudhZ7CZT1oy4mV6Wmnnod"
          ]
        },
        "version": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}


You're off to a great start. Parsing transaction data can be pretty tricky.
High level, I approach it similar to how you've set this up:

Filter for only transactions (not error/vote tx, includes our target program, and includes out target mint)

Then, Process the relevant transactions:

Find the Raydium instruction within the transaction
Make sure the instruction is a swap instruction (I am using the Raydium IDL--decoding the instruction data and getting the instruction name based on the 1st byte in the instruction data (corresponding to the ix index in the IDL)
Use the IDL to map the account names in the IDL to their position in the instruction data
Find the owner's token balance changes and subtract pre minus post to get the delta

Here's my working code (but I couldn't include the IDL here b/c of space). The full code available in this gist. There's a lot here--lmk if you have any questions or have any trouble with the code.
const VOTE_PROGRAM_ID = "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111";

// Target Mint (pnut)
const TARGET_MINT = "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump"; 
// These are the swap instructions
const TARGET_INSTRUCTION = ["swapBaseIn", "swapBaseOut"];
// These are the token accounts (and owner) involved in the swap
const TARGET_ACCOUNTS = ["userSourceTokenAccount", "userDestinationTokenAccount", "userSourceOwner"];


const isVoteTransaction = (tx) => {
    return tx.transaction?.message?.instructions?.some(inst =>
        inst.program === "vote" || inst.programId === VOTE_PROGRAM_ID
    );
};

const transactionError = (tx) => tx.meta?.err != null;

const invokesTargetProgram = (transaction, IDL) => {
    const targetProgram = IDL.address;
    const {
        meta: { logMessages = [], innerInstructions = [] },
        transaction: { message: { instructions = [] } }
    } = transaction;

    return instructions.some(inst => inst.programId === targetProgram) ||
        innerInstructions.some(inst => inst.instructions.some(innerInst => innerInst.programId === targetProgram)) ||
        logMessages.some(log => log.includes(`Program ${targetProgram} invoke [1]`));
};

const involvesTargetMint = (transaction) => {
    const {
        meta: { preTokenBalances = [], postTokenBalances = [] }
    } = transaction;

    return [...preTokenBalances, ...postTokenBalances].some(
        balance => balance.mint === TARGET_MINT
    );
}

const getTokenBalanceChanges = (preBalances, postBalances, ownerAddress) => {
    const filterByOwner = balances => balances.filter(balance => balance.owner === ownerAddress);

    const filteredBalances = {
        pre: filterByOwner(preBalances),
        post: filterByOwner(postBalances)
    };

    return filteredBalances.pre.map(mint => {
        const preBalance = filteredBalances.pre.find(balance => balance.mint === mint.mint);
        const postBalance = filteredBalances.post.find(balance => balance.mint === mint.mint);
        
        return {
            mint: mint.mint,
            owner: mint.owner,
            change: postBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount - preBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount,
            preBalance: preBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount,
            postBalance: postBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount,
        };
    });
};

const processInstruction = (ix, decodedData, preTokenBalances, postTokenBalances) => {
    // Get the 1st byte of the instruction data
    const discriminator = decodedData[0];
    // Get the instruction details from IDL (discriminator is the index)
    const idlInstruction = IDL.instructions[discriminator];
    // Get the instruction name from IDL
    const instructionName = idlInstruction.name;

    // Early returns for invalid cases
    if (!instructionName || !TARGET_INSTRUCTION.includes(instructionName)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Track the current account index separately from the IDL account index
    let txAccountIndex = 0;
    
    // Process accounts
    const accounts = idlInstruction.accounts
        .map(account => {
            if (!TARGET_ACCOUNTS.includes(account.name)) {
                txAccountIndex++;
                return null;
            }
            const accountAddress = ix.accounts[txAccountIndex++];
            return {
                accountName: account.name,
                accountAddress,
            };
        })
        .filter(Boolean);

    // Get owner address and process balance changes
    const ownerAccount = accounts.find(account => account.accountName === "userSourceOwner");
    if (!ownerAccount) return null;

    const ownerBalanceChanges = getTokenBalanceChanges(
        preTokenBalances,
        postTokenBalances,
        ownerAccount.accountAddress
    );

    return { ownerBalanceChanges };
};

function processTransaction(tx) {
    const { transaction, meta: { preTokenBalances = [], postTokenBalances = [] } } = tx;
    const signature = transaction.signatures[0];

    // Find Raydium AMM instructions
    const rayInstructions = transaction.message.instructions.filter(ix => 
        ix.programId === IDL.address
    );

    if (rayInstructions.length === 0) return null;

    // Process each instruction
    const decodedInstructions = rayInstructions
        .map(ix => {
            try {
                const decodedData = decodeBase58(ix.data);
                return processInstruction(ix, decodedData, preTokenBalances, postTokenBalances);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(`Error decoding instruction:`, e);
                return null;
            }
        })
        .filter(Boolean);

    return decodedInstructions.length > 0 ? {signature, ...decodedInstructions[0] } : null;
}

function main(stream) {
    try {
        const data = stream[0];
        if (!data?.transactions?.length) {
            return { error: 'Invalid or missing stream' };
        }

        const matchedTransactions = data.transactions
            .filter(tx => {
                const isTxValid = !transactionError(tx) && !isVoteTransaction(tx) && invokesTargetProgram(tx, IDL) && involvesTargetMint(tx);
                return isTxValid;
            })
            .map(tx => {
                const processedTx = processTransaction(tx, IDL);
                return processedTx;
            })
            .filter(Boolean);

        return matchedTransactions.length ? {
            numTx: matchedTransactions.length,
            transactions: matchedTransactions,
        } : { response: `No transactions found` };
    } catch (error) {
        return { error: error.message, stack: error.stack };
    }
}


function decodeBase58(encoded) {
    if (typeof encoded !== 'string') return [];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
        let carry = BASE58_ALPHABET.indexOf(encoded[i]);
        if (carry < 0) return []; // Invalid character, return empty array
        for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            carry += result[j] * 58;
            result[j] = carry & 0xff;
            carry >>= 8;
        }
        while (carry > 0) {
            result.push(carry & 0xff);
            carry >>= 8;
        }
    }
    // Add leading zeros
    for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length && encoded[i] === '1'; i++) {
        result.push(0);
    }
    return result.reverse();
}

const BASE58_ALPHABET = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz';

When I run this in the Stream setup test with block no: 303454197, I get the following output:
{
  "numTx": 1,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "ownerBalanceChanges": [
        {
          "change": -492.9951650000876,
          "mint": "2qEHjDLDLbuBgRYvsxhc5D6uDWAivNFZGan56P1tpump",
          "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
          "postBalance": 593418.273554,
          "preBalance": 593911.268719
        },
        {
          "change": 2.249098944999787,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "MfDuWeqSHEqTFVYZ7LoexgAK9dxk7cy4DFJWjWMGVWa",
          "postBalance": 13009.465832921,
          "preBalance": 13007.216733976
        }
      ],
      "txSignature": "4w7mexGkjC8cjqNiFTTTdMV2jakZZLWyLpxtiTAqoFU2yarkF3uKanoX4vdnaiSo11MudhZ7CZT1oy4mV6Wmnnod"
    }
  ]
}


Thank you for your reply! I’ve been testing the Stream setup code and encountered a few issues:

Websocket Error: Receiving an “Invalid or missing stream” message when I turned the stream on.
Some transactions that come through have empty balance array
Token Filtering: Struggling to filter for other tokens.

I’ve uploaded my code to a gist for review: Could you take a look or recommend resources on understanding IDLs better? Thanks! I added some comments in the code.
https://gist.github.com/GabrielWarner/49bbef8c5a29f49703dc68035f48db45


Let me look into the Invalid/missing stream error.
Empty Array...Can you share an example of a Tx or Txns that is returning an empty array that you'd expect to work?
Your modified mints filter looks okay to me. getTokenBalanceChanges
You shouldn't need userOwner b/c that field is not in either swap instruction.
I'd probably remove this unless you are certain you only want  SOL changes (you'd miss pairs like using USDC to buy PNUT, for example).

if (!solBalanceChange || solBalanceChange.change >= 0) {
        return null;
    }


WRT IDL--it's basically a mapping of how a Solana program works (in this case, Raydium) and your client. It outlines instructions, parameters, ordering of instructions, ordering of accounts...among other things.
Check this guide here for more detailson them. https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/anchor/what-is-an-idl
Unfortunately, there's not a single standard for IDLs. So they can be a little tricky. Compare IDL vs program:

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-idl/blob/master/raydium_amm/idl.json
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/ (check prg/src/instr)


If you use the code from the gist https://arc.net/l/quote/qnypagmm
These blocks return the empty array:
#303722998
#303696974
Here are the SOL scan links respectively:
https://solscan.io/tx/54Z3361vqrvLKKq5ZGMvh9Kdx7QQwZaVNavLo7AV9nANBsyafC3cfBCzmkw7YxghpSDtQhojFMsbTQ2Ngukp3K4v
https://solscan.io/tx/s5z8jhTUzrnARrFFp3UzcrzHi4Zqk1FkqRXqj4FKUfzTLS5wqrwyKVqTpPyY8Xf9LBVxkeZKTQCVJJcBRPcaKZg
Here is are transaction not coming through:
https://solscan.io/tx/4wrFSR3jCp63LBUCb6FgEFyVjAXo2CSXNPzwpRvyYZjmjRgZTgjtWrcT7CW3rF8x6eB72jNbLc9yrXiZXueZjqey

There are at least 2 issues I'm seeing: (1) raydium instruction allows for an optional account. This is messing up some of the owner name parsing and (2) some of the transactions close the wrapped SOL account, so the change is actually delta SOL not wrapped SOL. Working on a fix--I'll report back.

Give this a try: https://gist.github.com/amilz/e1a31d04ffd9316517ca908bd455326c (make sure on v2).



Changed architecture to class-based (I have been working on something else, and I think it makes this a bit more readable/easier to modify/debug)




Added support for multiple mints




Added native SOL support




Handled 0 pre-balance token accounts




Handled optional accounts for Raydium's swap instructions
This is working for all the blocks/txns you sent.



